# Regex in AWK's not accepting lazy selection

Tags: regex, awk

I have following text file from which I want to extract what is between "NAME=" and the first following "," or ")" character.

```
  AZTBCM         = (CURVE=(NAME=AZTBCM), -SOME TEXT
  B08M           = (CURVE=(NAME=B08M), -  SOME TEXT
  YMOD         = (CURVE=(NAME=YMOD), - SOME TEXT
  ZCCP         = (CURVE=(NAME=ZCCP, CURVE TYPE= GAMMA), - SOME TEXT
```

The character ranges and lazy selections however in gensub don't work as they would do in say nedit. In following awk-script file you can find the different lines I tried

```
#! /bin/awk -f
{name=gensub(/.*NAME=(.*?)[,)].*/,"\\1","g",$0); print "line1 "name}        #line1
{name=gensub(/.*NAME=([:alnum:]*?)[,)].*/,"\\1","g",$0); print "line2 "name}    #line2
{name=gensub(/.*NAME=([0-z ]*?)[,)].*/,"\\1","g",$0); "line3 "print name}   #line3
{name=gensub(/.*NAME=([0-z Z]*?)[,)].*/,"\\1","g",$0); "line4 "print name}  #line4
{name=gensub(/.*NAME=([0-Z0-9]*?)[,)].*/,"\\1","g",$0); "line5 "print name} #line5
```

This produces following:

```
line1 AZTBCM)
line2       AZTBCM         = (CURVE=(NAME=AZTBCM), -SOME TEXT
line3       AZTBCM         = (CURVE=(NAME=AZTBCM), -SOME TEXT
line4 AZTBCM
line5 AZTBCM
line1 B08M)
line2       B08M           = (CURVE=(NAME=B08M), -  SOME TEXT
line3 B08M
line4 B08M
line5 B08M
line1 YMOD)
line2       YMOD         = (CURVE=(NAME=YMOD), - SOME TEXT
line3 YMOD
line4 YMOD
line5 YMOD
line1 ZCCP, CURVE TYPE= GAMMA)
line2       ZCCP         = (CURVE=(NAME=ZCCP, CURVE TYPE= GAMMA), - SOME TEXT
line3       ZCCP         = (CURVE=(NAME=ZCCP, CURVE TYPE= GAMMA), - SOME TEXT
line4 ZCCP
line5 ZCCP
```

Line 1 returns just the name including a ")". My lazy qualifier should have prevented this. Nedit using the same selection/replacement gives just the name. Looking at the ZCCP case it even seems to continue capturing up to and including the last parenthesis.

Line2 returns no match and thus returns $0. Can't get this get to work in Nedit either.(seems unsupported, that's ok)

Line3 should take zero to lower z of the ascii table. This to me is the strangest fail. As I had loads more of lines this only fails whenever there is a Z in the name. Not even in low caps like the terminating character in my character range.

Line 4 I added space and Z (actually no need for space) to see if the character range misses it for some unknown reason. And there seems to be one as it now works again.
Forget about line 5 :)

Can anyone shed light primarily how this capturing works in case of line one? I don't see why it pushes on for that first parenthesis. Secondly why is my character range not including the "Z"?

Cheers,Robbert

PS this question appeared to be two folded. So I changed the title of this post as to what was aqtually answered.

Comment: Note, this `[:alnum:]` is a character class, and they need to appear inside a bracket expression, so you need: `[[:alnum:]]` -- without the outer brackets, you can match `:` or `a` or `l` or `n` or `u` or `m`

Comment: Also, `[0-z]` is the set 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,:,;,<,=,>,?,@,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,[,\,],^,_,`,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z -- do you want to match all that?

Comment: `*` is the RE metacharacter to repeat the previous RE segment 0 or more times. `?`  is the RE metacharacter to repeat the previous RE segment 0 or 1 times. So when you write `*?` I'm not even sure what that would mean to awk but it almost certainly isn't whatever it is you THINK it should mean. I think the issue is you're trying to use some kind of RE language that is not EREs as defined by POSIX, which is what awk understands. See @devnull's answer for the way to do what you want in awk.

Comment: (.*?)[,)] will capture any character up till it sees its fisrt , or ). It will turn greedy capturing (in which it will capture all up till the last ,) on the line) into lazy capturing in which all is captured up till the first occurence on the line. So (.*?)[,)] will capture : "      ZCCP         = (CURVE=(NAME=ZCCP," instead of "      ZCCP         = (CURVE=(NAME=ZCCP, CURVE TYPE= GAMMA)". And indeed it is not doing what I think it should be doing or as what Nedit is doing.

Comment: @RobbertKoppenol - there's no such thing as what you're referring to as `lazy capturing` in EREs (what awk uses). Maybe that's something in Perl REs?

Comment: Perfect, that must be it for the capturing. Only thing left is that character range thing. Can you see why "awk '{name=gensub(/.*NAME=([0-z ]*)[,)].*/,"\\1","g",$0); print "line3 "name}' testfile.txt" does not return my NAME item?

Comment: I'm guessing NAME= is followed by some character that in your locale is not included in the character list you specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this comment:
`My question is more academic as to why it does not work for awk lines 1 and 3. I just can't find any logic to it.`

Here's what the REs used in those lines mean:

```
.*NAME=(.*?)[,)].*
```

From the start of the line to NAME= followed by any character repeated 0 or more times then repeated 0 or more times (yes it makes no sense) followed by a , or ) followed by any character repeated 0 or more times. So, the part inside the `()` will match from the character after the `NAME=` to the character before the last `,` or `)` on the line.

```
.*NAME=([0-z ]*?)[,)].*
```

From the start of the line to NAME= followed by any character within the range `0` to `z` (whatever that means in your locale - it may or may not be exactly the list Glenn Jackman gave in his comment but it'll be something like that) or a blank char repeated 0 or more times then repeated 0 or more times (yes it makes no sense) followed by a , or ) followed by any character repeated 0 or more times. So, the part inside the `()` will match from the character after the `NAME=` to the character before the last `,` or `)` or the first occurrence of any character not in the specified range on the line.

Oh, and as to why `Z` isn't included in your range `0-z` - the characters in that range are dependent on your locale. `a-z`, for example can be `abc...z` or it can be `aAbBcC...z` (i.e. does not include `Z`). Use POSIX character classes instead of explicit ranges for portability, e.g. `[[:lower:]]`, `[[:upper:]]`, `[[:alpha:]]`, etc.

Comment: Hi ed. Things go quick here:) That lazy qualifier not being supported makes sense now. That Z maybe as well, working on a Norwegian machine here. I thought it was just the ASCII table as-is being used. And my Z is in the range in there. OK, embarassing I guess, but where the hell do I find my locale so I can see what my range is actually capturing. (I just popped up an ASCII table from the net.) But note taken, "use character classes".

Comment: That character set @glenn provided should work fine, but that's from the ascii table I asumed it to use. Where to find what range my pc actually uses?

Comment: Just use character classes or set `LC_ALL=C` and you don't have to worry about whatever the default is that you don't want.

Comment: I am afraid the Z mystery is still on as I found my charmap to be ISO-8859-15, having the Z within the 0-z range. I used locale charmap to find the table. Also LC_ALL=C didn't help.

Comment: Close this one out and post a new question showing some minimal example that demonstrates ONLY the specific problem you're asking about now with some sample input and expected output along with what you've tried for THIS specific issue.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of attempting to use lazy quantifiers, you might have used a negated character class.  Saying:

```
awk '{name=gensub(/.*NAME=([^,)]*).*/,"\\1","g",$0); print "line1 "name}' filename
```

would produce the following for your input:

```
line1 AZTBCM
line1 B08M
line1 YMOD
line1 ZCCP
```

Comment: I actually had it working already as per line 4. My question is more academic as to why it does not work for awk lines 1 and 3. I just can't find any logic to it.

Comment: Ed's comment answers that.